# Why php file encoding influence response data encoding?

Tags: php, json, file, encoding, response

I make simple web server responsing JSON string with PHP.

It had worked well until I changed some php files with Notepad++.

From the moment I changed some php files with Notepad++, my mobile client have made the error

> CompanyName.ProjectName.V1.Client.ApiException: Unexpected character
>   encountered while parsing value: . Path ", line 0, position 0.`.

I solved this problem, deleting 'UTF-8 BOM(Binary Order Mask)' at first of php files.

But, as far as I know PHP is script language. Why PHP file encoding influence response data encoding?
In Python, same script language like PHP, there is no problem with file encoding.

Because I don't know much about PHP, I wonder why that happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP expects scripts to conform to the Unicode standard. According to the Unicode standard, the BOM for UTF-8 files is not recommended:

> 2.6 Encoding Schemes
>
> Use of a BOM is neither required nor recommended for UTF-8, but may be
>   encountered in contexts where UTF-8 data is converted from other
>   encoding forms that use a BOM or where the BOM is used as a UTF-8
>   signature. See the “Byte Order Mark” subsection in Section 16.8,
>   Specials, for more information.

Hat tip: [What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom)

You may want to consider using editing software that correctly deals with PHP. I like Atom (https://atom.io/), a free, open source software that supports PHP and many other languages.